# How to avoid maven to request private artifacts from public repositories?

Tags: maven

I have a pom file with my own repository as first, and a set of public repositories next (repo1, repo2, java.net, etc.). Let's assume all are "release" repositories.

My problem is that maven does a request into all repositories looking for our internal jars, either to download the jar the first time, or to verify the metadata.xml if the versioning is a range like "(1.0.0,1.1.0]".

How can I apply some kind of filters to state something like the groupID foo.bar belong only to the repository "foo".

This case bothers me for two reasons: one is that it's a waste of bandwidth to do these requests into the public servers (and when a server is slow, it just slows down everything), and second it exposes the name of our internal packages into the outside world's log files.

I don't want to deploy a local proxy or anything like that, just want a certain groupID (or list of) to always go to a certain repository. Even for non private artifacts, it would help to specify that a certain artifact is on a certain repository, for such artifacts that are not on the public generic ones (repo.maven, download.java), and hence avoid those redundant requests.

Comment: I know you said that you don't like a local proxy, but shouldn't any useful local repository software also include the ability to provide a simple local proxy of the public repositories?

Comment: my local repository is a simple webdav enabled apache. I wouldn't want to setup anything more complicated than that.

Comment: let me further explain: the local repository is meant to be simple and tidy and small, as I can at any time just clean it up and rebuild the relevant artifacts from Jenkins, and I don't want to proxy and consume local disk resources. For the same reason, I don't want to consume http request resources by asking every repository for every artifact, specially not the internal ones being asked into the public ones.

Comment: I understand the reasoning, I was just asking for clarification. Good question, btw.

Answer (score 2):

We use internal Nexus instance and have such thing configured there. Nexus has it at `Administration -> Routing` option where you can define masks for `groupId` and point which repositories should be used then.

Of course it needs internal Nexus to be the only repository used by developers and then configure any external repositories to be proxied or mirrored.